# java.util.date to java.sql.date conversion NPE

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception, type-conversion

I am trying to set up a method to convert java.util.date typed variables into java.sql.date typed variables so they can be persisted to database.  However, the code I set up keeps returning a null pointer exception, even though I am getting values on the argument being passed into the method.

```
public static java.sql.Date convertUtilDateSQLDate(java.util.Date utilDate){

        long utilDateTime = utilDate.getTime();

        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDateTime);

        return sqlDate;

    }
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you please verify that `utilDate` is not null?

Comment: You are probably giving it a null argument.

Comment: utilDate is not null; I have even tested the value of long utilDateTime before instantiating the sqlDate object, and it has a long value.

Comment: You are correct, I have identified that there is a null in the pipeline - I am having an issue with reading in an Excel date into the java.util.date using the Apache POI - the cell.getDateCellValue is not reading it in as a date.

Comment: Figured out the issue was that as I was reading down the Excel file rows inside of a while loop using rows.next(), it was reading blank rows even though there were no values in the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utilDate` object might be null. Include NULL check condition to avoid it. like.

```
public static java.sql.Date convertUtilDateSQLDate(java.util.Date utilDate){

         if( utilDate == null){
              //add log and return;
              return null;
          }
            long utilDateTime = utilDate.getTime();
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDateTime);
            return sqlDate;

        }
```

If `utilDate` is null, then this method returns the NULL back, so the method which invokes this `convertUtilDateSQLDate()` method should also do the NULL check.